# models and I need only date from

Tags: python, models

Base model

```
class EmployeeDetails(models.Model):

employee_ID=models.IntegerField()
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#checkin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
#checkout = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now , blank = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Checkin model use the employee details created using "employee details" model

```
class Checkin(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE )
employee_ID = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDetails,on_delete =models.CASCADE)
checkin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
checkin1 = datetime.datetime.today()

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.employee_ID)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.employee_ID)
```

Checkout model which uses the content of "employee details" model

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
employee_ID = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDetails,on_delete =models.CASCADE)
checkout = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.employee_ID)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.employee_ID)
```

Comment: @scharette                                                                           these are my actual models . i tried using your suggestion in forms like "checkin = DateTimeField(input_formats=["%b %d"])" but got "name error"

Comment: What is your Question? Please clearly state your question.

Comment: in both of Checkin and Checkout models i have " DateTimeField" that gives output in the format "nov 11 2017 11:52:00" out of which i need only date as "nov 11 2017" to write a validation in my forms